# Insufficient privileges on cross-reference id - on trying to update a specific Account on contact

Tags: apex, visualforce, trigger, administration, system-admin

When I am trying to update a contact with Account A and click on save, I am receiving the error "Insufficient privileges on cross-reference id "

When I try updating the same contact with another Account B, I can successfully save the record.
I have compared the record types of both Accounts A, B and I see the Record types are the same

What could be the reason, Any help!
Thanks

Comment: Check the sharing rules on the relevant records.

Comment: There are a couple of more clarifications which are important i.e. what are the sharing settings for Accounts / Contacts ? Do you have sharing rules, Territory sharing etc? who's the owner of the Account ?

Comment: You must review the sharing setting for Account A. The user doesn't have the correct access to the Account.